# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Not unique table/alias: 'usuarios_grupos'

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot seem to find the error in my MySQL query. It states that I have not unique table alias for table `usuarios_grupos`

However, my table `usuarios_grupos` only appears once!

My query is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
WHERE usuarios.id_usuario
NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT id_usuario FROM usuarios_grupos, grupos
WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = grupos.id_grupo)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can get rid of the second DISTINCT - NOT IN handles duplicates returned by the subquery for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table `usuarios_grupos` appears once but `id_usuario` might be in two tables so you have to be specific and try use join instead and there are no need for `Distict` like this:

```
SELECT usuarios.id_usuario
FROM usuarios
WHERE usuarios.id_usuario
NOT IN 
(
   SELECT ug.id_usuario 
   FROM usuarios_grupos ug inner join grupos g 
   on ug.id_grupo = g.id_grupo
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If id_usuario appear both in usuarios_grupos and grupos, you'll have to tell MySQL which one you want to use:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT grupos.id_usuario FROM usuarios_grupos, grupos
  WHERE usuarios_grupos.id_grupo = grupos.id_grupo
```